# Finding index 2 subgroups of the affine general linear group

Tags: group-theory

I need to show that AGL(1,$\mathbb{R}$) has an index 2 subgroup but that AGL(1,$\mathbb{C}$) does not. I also need to find for which finite fields, $\mathbb{F}$, AGL(1,$\mathbb{F}$) has an index 2 subgroup.

To show AGL(1,$\mathbb{C}$) does not have an index 2 subgroup, I think that I need to show that every proper subgroup has infinite index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: An index 2 subgroup has abelian quotient, so contains the derived subgroup. Calculate the commutator of two general elements to see there is a nice answer.

> The derived subgroup contains the commutator of $x\mapsto x+1$ and $x\mapsto (1+a) x$, which is $x \mapsto x-a$. Thus the derived subgroup contains all translations*. Hence for a field $K$, $\operatorname{AGL}(1,K)$ has an index 2 subgroup if and only if its maximal abelian quotient, $K^\times$, has an index 2 subgroup. $\mathbb{R}^\times$ has one; $\mathbb{C}^\times$ does not; a finite $\mathbb{F}^\times$ has one iff $\mathbb{F}$ has odd characteristic. The field $\mathbb{F}$ of size 2 is an exception*, since $\operatorname{AGL}(1,\mathbb{F})\cong \mathbb{F}_+$ has a subgroup of index 2, but $\mathbb{F}^\times\cong 1$ does not.

Tricky detail:

> *As long as the field is larger than size 2; in char 2 but bigger than $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ one can use that the commutator $x\mapsto ax+1$ and $x\mapsto cx+1$ is $x \mapsto x+a+c$ to get the translations. If $|\mathbb{F}|=2$, then we get $\operatorname{AGL}(1,\mathbb{F})$ is cyclic of order 2, so is a special case.

Comment: Is it easy to show that $\mathbb{R}^×$ has an index 2 subgroup; $\mathbb{C}^×$ does not; and that a finite $\mathbb{F}^×$ has one iff F has odd characteristic?

Comment: I think so. The are two types of nonzero reals, the ____ and the ____. If $H \leq \mathbb{C}^\times$ has index 2, then $z^2 \in H$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}^\times$, but every nonzero complex number has a square root. Which elements of finite fields have square roots?

Comment: That confirms what I had thought for $\mathbb{R}^×$, but I don't understand the connection between index 2 and square roots

Comment: In any group $G$ if $H\leq G$ has index 2, then $g^2 \in H$ for every $g \in G$. If $x=g^2$, then $x \in H$. Given $x$ how do you find $g$ such that $g^2=x$?

Comment: So, $\mathbb{C}^×$ can't have an index 2 subgroup, because if it did, then that subgroup would contain every element, which is a contradiction.

I can see from a few calculations that it does look like you can split a finite field into 2 by those that have square roots and those that don't if the field has odd characteristic. Is there a way to say this definitely happens for odd characteristic and not for even?

Comment: Correct.  Finite fields have cyclic multiplicative groups, so squaring is well-understood: if the order of the multiplicative group is odd, then squaring is an automorphism, but if the order of the multiplicative group is even, then the image is an index 2 subgroup (just a general fact about cyclic groups). A finite field of char 2 has a multiplicative group of order $2^n-1$, odd. A finite field of odd char has a multiplicative group of order $q^n-1$, even.

Comment: Is it a fact that for $H\leq G$ with index $n$ then $g^n\in H$? Or does this only work for $n=2$?

Comment: You need $H$ to be normal to be guaranteed. If $H \unlhd G$ with index $n$ then $g^n \in H$. This is Lagrange's theorem.  If $H$ is not normal, then the bound is less impressive (for instance $g^{n!} \in H$). For $n=2$, $H$ is automatically normal, and the $n!$ bound is still equal to 2.